# Referencing multiple dictionaries to workbook module

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, reference

I would like to call separate `Sub` procedures from the workbook module ThisWorkbook to run calculations upon workbook open.

I am using early binding to create dictionaries and from that `Sub` I am calling the next `Sub` and referencing the dictionaries.

Can I place the whole dictionary creation procedure in a separate module, call it from the workbook module ThisWorkbook and then reference the dictionaries in the next `Sub` procedure that is called from the workbook module?

This is what I have:

```
'----------------------------
'Workbook module ThisWorkbook
'----------------------------

Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Dim MRMT As Workbook
Dim ER As Worksheet

Set MRMT = Excel.Workbooks("MRMT")
Set ER = MRMT.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ER
    .Name = "Exposure Report"
End With

Import_Exposure_Report MRMT, ER

' I would like to have "Create_Dictionaries" procedure in a separate 
' module and then pass the dictionaries to the Sub below from this workbook module

Import_Historical_Data MRMT, ER  'Key1, Key2, Key3 ect.

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand - why it is you want to do this?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, the dictionary creation is quite long - about 650 lines and, also, I may be needing them in a later state of the code. Just wandering if I can make them "Global" for the workbook and reference them.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, also, I wouldn't like to create the dictionaries in the class module... Although this is the only way I see at present to have what I want.

Comment: If it’s that involved you could pass the resulting dictionary out of the function you create it in as an object

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, could you dirrect me to an example, please?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, please see the edit of my question.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, I don't think that the Late Binding will work for the purpose, as I need the Early Binding for a `For...Next` loop...

Comment: How many dictionaries are you trying to create? Are they all similar?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, six dictionaries. They do not contain values, keys only. What other similarities are you referring to?

Comment: As in whether they're generated/filled in the same way or have at least similar inputs

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, 
`Dim CommoditiesDict As Scripting.Dictionary` 
`Set CommoditiesDict = New Scripting.Dictionary` 
`CommoditiesDict.Add "#Oil", ""`
This is how all six dictionaries look like.

Comment: Ahh hm. Then it might not hurt just to post the whole thing so I can understand how it’s so long if the declaration is that simple

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, It is just 650 lines like `CommoditiesDict.Add "#Oil", ""`.

Comment: So it’s just 600 lines of different? items being added to these dictionaries?

Comment: @Mrcucciboy2, yes. I'd like to move them out of the specific module that they are populating at the moment, move them to a separate module and reference them to the class workbook module ThisWorkbook, from where they can be referenced to various other modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Dim MRMT As Workbook
    Dim ER As Worksheet

    Dim CommoditiesDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim IndexesDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim StocksDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim CryptoDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim BondsDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim FXDict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set MRMT = Excel.Workbooks("MRMTool_V7")
    Set ER = MRMT.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ER.Name = "Exposure Report"

    With MRMT

        Import_Exposure_Report MRMT, ER

        Create_Dictionaries BondsDict, CryptoDict, CommoditiesDict, IndexesDict, FXDict, StocksDict, MRMT

        Populate_Historical_Data BondsDict, CryptoDict, CommoditiesDict, IndexesDict, FXDict, StocksDict, MRMT, ER

    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```